# Trim, strip_tags or mysqli_real_escape_string for protection of user input?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

In php, what would be the better way to protect against malicious user input:

```
  $password = trim($_POST['password']);
  $password = strip_tags($password);
  $password = htmlspecialchars($password);
```

Or

```
mysqli_real_escape_string(connection,$_POST['password']);
```

Or is there a even better way?

Comment: Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Thank you, I did not think about this! :)